# How to add form of payment using PNR_AddmultiElements Amadeus webservice

Tags: amadeus

What should be the xml query structured for adding a form of payment as "INV AGT"

using pnr_addmultielemets. The following code produces FP line as "MS INVAGT".

Is there something that i am missing?

```
<PNR_AddMultiElements>
  <pnrActions>
    <optionCode>11</optionCode>
  </pnrActions>
  <dataElementsMaster>
    <marker1 />
    <dataElementsIndiv>
      <elementManagementData>
        <segmentName>FP</segmentName>
      </elementManagementData>
      <formOfPayment>
        <fop>
          <identification>MS</identification>
        </fop>
      </formOfPayment>
      <fopExtension>
        <fopSequenceNumber>1</fopSequenceNumber>
        <newFopsDetails>
          <printedFreeflow>INV AGT</printedFreeflow>
        </newFopsDetails>
      </fopExtension>
      <referenceForDataElement>
        <reference>
          <qualifier>ST</qualifier>
          <number>1</number>
        </reference>
      </referenceForDataElement>
    </dataElementsIndiv>
    <dataElementsIndiv>
      <elementManagementData>
        <segmentName>RF</segmentName>
      </elementManagementData>
      <freetextData>
        <freetextDetail>
          <subjectQualifier>3</subjectQualifier>
          <type>P2</type>
        </freetextDetail>
        <longFreetext>admin</longFreetext>
      </freetextData>
    </dataElementsIndiv>
  </dataElementsMaster>
</PNR_AddMultiElements>
```

Comment: Are you able to show us what you are using at the moment so we can help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<PNR_AddMultiElements>
<pnrActions>
    <optionCode>11</optionCode>
</pnrActions>
<dataElementsMaster>
    <marker1/>
    <dataElementsIndiv>
        <elementManagementData>
            <segmentName>FP</segmentName>
        </elementManagementData>
        <formOfPayment>
            <fop>
                <identification>MS</identification>
                <freetext>INV AGT</freetext>
            </fop>           
        </formOfPayment>
    </dataElementsIndiv>
    <dataElementsIndiv>
        <elementManagementData>
            <segmentName>RF</segmentName>
        </elementManagementData>
        <freetextData>
            <freetextDetail>
                <subjectQualifier>3</subjectQualifier>
                <type>P2</type>
            </freetextDetail>
            <longFreetext>admin</longFreetext>
        </freetextData>
    </dataElementsIndiv>
</dataElementsMaster>
```

Comment: I tried and it gives the following error in PNR_Replay. We had tried this option earlier but this did not help. Tried again but its gives invalid form of payment error

Comment: Try it with removing the space on INV AGT to be <freetext>INVAGT</freetext>?